# Immer drafts, computed properties

Tags: javascript, redux, immer.js

Im not sure why I'm getting `Error: Immer drafts cannot have computed properties` in my reducer code. I'm using `redux-starter-kit` which wraps all my reducer code with the Immer library.

I'm not entirely sure what Immer is referring to with "computed property." Does it mean getters/setters? Because I'm not creating any getters or setters explicitly. Is the object spread operator doing it?

Do getters/setters contaminate the state object somehow?

Or is computed property in reference to computed property names? https://tylermcginnis.com/computed-property-names/

My reducer is fairly simple:

```
import { createSlice } from 'redux-starter-kit' 

const assets = createSlice({
  slice: 'assets',
  initialState: {byName: {}},
  reducers: {
    upload: (state, action) => {
        const {name} = action.payload;
        state.byName[name].status = 'uploading';
    },
    initialize: (state, action) => {
        const {assets, id} = action.payload;
        assets.forEach(({name, uri}) => {
            state.byName[name] = {
                uri,
                name,
                status: 'local',
                id,
                inProgress: true
            };
        });
    },
  }
})
export default assets;
```

The assets/initialize action is triggered first with no error, and the immer error occurs when the assets/upload action is triggered

[image: assets/initialize output]

I'm not sure where all those get name / set name, get uri / set uri fields are coming from. Is that what Immer is complaining about?

[image: assets/upload output]

I rewrote the upload reducer to create a new object,

```
upload: (state, action) => {
    const {name} = action.payload;
    state.byName[name] = {
        ...state.byName[name],
        status: 'uploading',
    };
},
```

and the error I get now is equally baffling:

[image: assets/upload error output]

Comment: You should post a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you using React, Vue or something else?

Comment: Using React Native. I'll work on a repro.

Comment: Not sure if you ever solved your issue.  In my case, I wound up trying to reproduce it, and somehow recreated my entire app without reproducing the problem.  In the end, I cleaned yarn's cache, deleted the node_modules folder, and reinstalled my dependencies from scratch -- which solved the problem.  Something *very* odd going on here.

Comment: Correction: I actually found the issue.  It's my initial state -- electron was messing with the data I was sending back and forth, and that somehow messed my state up completely.

Comment: I've been having this problem as well. I think that fetch is building the results object as a bunch of computed properties, which you are putting directly on state, and then trying to modify with immer.

Answer (score -3):

> I'm not sure where all those get name / set name, get uri / set uri fields are coming from. Is that what Immer is complaining about?

These "fields" come from Redux, and yes, that's what Immer is complaining about. They're called Acessors - but mostly known as Getter and Setter - which were introduced in ES5. This is by design Redux's way to work with state, which is to mutate the object and track changes through these functions - your reducers become setters, and selectors become getters. Now Immer's approach is to provide an immutable state tree, providing a new object on every state change.

Immer complains about these acessors because there's no way to clone object with functions 100% reliably, as these may be accessing lexically-scoped private variables through closures, i.e. these function bodies variable references would point to the previous state (more on that on ["how do javascript closures work"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)). And this isn't an Immer-specific problem, it is the very specification of how the JavaScript structured clone algorithm work. As per MDN comment on [the structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm):

> The structured clone algorithm is an algorithm defined by the HTML5 specification for copying complex JavaScript objects. (...)
>
> ## Things that don't work with structured cloneSection
>
> - Error and Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to do so will throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.
> - Attempting to clone DOM nodes will likewise throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.
> - **Certain parameters of objects are not preserved:**
>
>   - The lastIndex field of RegExp objects is not preserved.
>   - **Property descriptors, setters, and getters** (as well as similar metadata-like features) are not duplicated. For example, if an object is marked read-only using a property descriptor, it will be read-write in the duplicate, since that's the default condition.
>   - The prototype chain does not get walked and duplicated.

Note that prototype computed property names do work with Immer if you set it as "immerable" with `prototype[immerable] = true`, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Im not using Vue

Comment: @frank indeed, but the concept still applies. I've rephrased so it now refers specifically to redux.

Comment: This cannot be right. I tried this in code sandbox, and it's not true. Here is my sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/immer-computed-properties-redux-2mzxf

Comment: I don't think this answer is at all right.  Redux doesn't add getters/setters.  It may be coming from somewhere else, but redux relies on the coder to create a new object and return that, leaving the original unmutated.  ReduxStarterKit adds immer and wraps the reducers in that, so the fields *may* be coming from there, but they're certainly not coming from redux itself.